# Unix: is there an alternative to expect command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, ssh

I am trying to do a bash script in order to autoconnect into a ssh server.
However I don't have permissions to install the expect package.
So I would like to know if there is a way to automatically enter "yes" when asked and then enter the password when asked without using the expect command?

I work on xubuntu.

In summary this is what I would like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh user@localhost << EOT
#enter "yes" here when asked
#enter my password here when asked
ls
EOT
```

Comment: What is preventing you from setting up a passwordless connection ?

Comment: Perl has some ssh modules that I'm pretty sure come standard.

Comment: What is the "yes" for?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming [setting up an SSH key](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/) pair is not an option, nor is installing [sshpass](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-applesox-ssh-password-on-command-line/), you can resort to [this solution](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/587) (ab)using `$SSH_ASKPASS`.